# Parse XML string to List/DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, datatable

I have a `XML string` given below with 2 columns `no` and `Active`

**XML -**

```
<RECORDS RECORDCOUNT="2">
    <RECORD COL_HEADER="0">
        <no>201738</no>
        <Active>-1</Active>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD COL_HEADER="0">
        <no>201739</no>
        <Active>0</Active>
    </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

And to convert the above `XML string` to `list` i have tried to `Parse` with the below `LINQ expression`

**LINQ - Expression**

```
var result = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
                    .Descendants().Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Value))
                    .Select(r => int.Parse(r.Value))
                    .ToList();
```

**Error -**

> Input string was not in a correct format.

In the result set i am expecting both the columns with their respective values. Do i have to use `datatable` or any other other than `list`.

Please help!
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually <RECORD COL_HEADER="0"> contain value, you must add to your Where an additional check to be like this

```
Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Value) && (r.Name == "no" || r.Name == "Active"))
```

to obtain your expectation u can try this:

```
var result = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
.Descendants().
Where(x => x.Name == "RECORD")
.Select(x => new
{
    no = int.Parse(x.Element("no").Value),
    Active = int.Parse(x.Element("Active").Value)
}
).ToList();
```

Comment: But it does not have a specified column name to use for further processing on data.

Comment: Yes, That worked! But how to order the result set by `Active = -1` always. i.e. the records with `Active = -1` should be up than the other ones with `0`

Comment: u can add .OrderBy(x => x.Active) after ToList()

Comment: Doesn't work when i try to get access to the element values, may be because of `var`?

Comment: OrderBy(x => x.Active) `before` ToList()?

Comment: yes before, or you will get an IOrderedEnumerable as a result instead of List

Answer (score 2):

You're only going down one level then attempting to parse the all the sub elements

```
<RECORD COL_HEADER="0">
  <no> 201738 </no>
  <Active> -1 </Active>
</RECORD>
```

into an int. You need to get them out individually, something like so

```
List<Record> records = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
    .Descendants("RECORD")
    .Select(x => new Record((int)x.Element("no"), (int)x.Element("Active")))
    .ToList();


public class Record
{
    public readonly int No;
    public readonly int Active;

    public Record(int no, int active)
    {
        this.No = no;
        this.Active = active;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't i get without the `Record` class?

Comment: yes of course! You can pretty much manipulate it however you want. Karmin has just edited his answer showing how to use an anonymous type. How do you want it to look once its in the list and I'll edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use this way instead of using `Descendants`:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root?               // => RECORDS 
    .Elements()                                             // => RECORD
    .Select(c => new {
        no =  int.Parse(c.Element("no")?.Value ?? "0"), 
        active = c.Element("Active")?.Value == "-1"})
    .ToList();
```